# CSS background color and png color inconsistent between browsers

Tags: css

I am using a `png` image as background for a single page website. I want the background of the `png` to match the background of the page as I scroll down so that it looks continuous. I've set the `background-color` value to `#EC966A`. On my mac it shows correctly in Firefox and Chrome but not on Safari.

The transition in Firefox and Chrome:

[image: Firefox and Chrome]

The transition in Safari:

[image: Safari]

I had someone test it on Windows and it shows wrong on Chrome and Firefox as well.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <P>This is the image:</P> 
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpYQq.png" alt="">
    <p>and this is the background</p>
    <div class="bg" style="background-color: #EC966A; width: 335px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Without testing this for ourselves it's hard to comment. Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks! I've added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is about images color profiling which can lead to different rendering on different browsers.

You can read more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/

**EDIT:**

Your img has a *RGB* profile. So I converted it to *sRGB* which is the recommended color profile for the web.

OUTPUT:

```css
.bg{
  background:#DE9964;
  width:332px;
  height:91px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/29bld6r.png">
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Now it should look the same both on Chrome and Safari.

Tested on Mac OS X - Chrome 48.0 and Safari 9.0.3

Comment: Than you for your answer. I read the article and the discussion but it does not seem to offer a solution. It describes problems between different images but my issue is between an image and a `css` background. I will post some code.